# In the blockchain split of March 2013, where should miners mine, 0.7 or 0.8?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-fork, march-2013-fork

I want a clear cut answer + references so they is no confusion.

Today March 12 2013, on which fork should miners mine, 0.7 or 0.8?

Comment: No more fork.  So it doesn't matter anymore.  Well, both are mining the same blockchain, but v0.8 nodes could still be configured to mine a block that v0.7 won't accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should go to 0.7, despite the fact that this is the version containing the error. This choice was made because it should be much easier to get the few who upgraded to bleeding-edge 0.8 to downgrade than to get everyone to upgrade all at once.

Sources:

- https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=152030
- http://codinginmysleep.com/blockchain-all-forked-up/
- http://bitcoin.org/chainfork.html

Comment: Yes, I agree to David